# API data retrieval with requests.get in Python keeps sending me back the same exact batch of data inside a Django View

Tags: python, while-loop, django-views, python-requests

Hello everyone and thanks a lot for your time.

I'm facing a really weird problem. There is this organization that has this API service up for us to retrieve data fronm them. It is a simple URL that returns a JSON with exactly 100 records.

So I created a Python code to retrieve this data and store it into our local database. So everytime we run the code, we get 100 records until the organization's API gets empty and there's nothing else to respond until the next day. So just to be clear. If the organization want's us to import 360 records, we have to run the API GET call 4 times, 3 times to get batches of 100 records and the fourth time to retrieve the last 60 records. After that if I run it for a 5th time, the response tells me there are no more records for the day.

So, my problem starts here, I wanted run the API GET call inside a while loop to retrive all the JSONs and store them on a list. But inside the while loop whenever we run again the API GET call, its response is the exact same one as the previous response. The data doesn't change at all and the API on the organization's side, doesn't send any more batches of records, because there are no requests from us. Let me show you how it looks.

```
import requests

listOfResponses = []
tempResponseList = []

while True:
    tempResponseList = requests.get(url = apiURL, headers = headers, params = params).json()

    if tempResponseList:
        listOfResponses.append(tempResponseList)
        tempResponseList = []
    else:
        print('There are no more records')
        break
```

I have read many more articles regarding that te problem may be on the `keep-alive` property of the `requests` library in Python, but no matter what I try, it won't reset either the connection or the refresh the API GET call to retreive new data. I'm tied to having to run the program the times needed to retrieve all the data from the API.

I tried adding the `{ 'Connection':'close' }` parameter on the headers of the request and it closed the connection but still no new data.

I tried ussing the `requests.Session()` method and closing the session but still no solution:

```
s = requests.Session()
 #all the code above executed but instead of requests.get, I used s.get
 #and then it was followed by this
s.close()
```

I also even tried a solution posted here at the forum that suggested adding this code after the `s.close()`:

```
s.mount('http://', requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter())
s.mount('https://', requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter())
```

I'm a little bit confused with this so any help, observations or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any thoughts? Any help will be gratly appreciated.

Comment: So.. I'm going to die ignored? :(